# Keep users in Config.groovy list in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, config

Is there any way to define the users that can use my application in a list in Config.groovy? This will be using Grails 2.2.3 and the latest versions of Spring Security Core and Spring Security LDAP.

We use Active Directory for authentication, and only 2 or 3 people will use this little application, so it doesn't seem worthy of making an AD Group for just this app. It would be simpler to define a list, and any time there is a new hire instead of adding them to the AD group all I have to do is add their name to the external Grails config.

I would like to do something like the following:

SomeController.groovy

```
@Secured("authentication.name in grailsApplication.config.my.app.usersList")
class SomeController {

}
```

Then in Config.groovy put this code:

```
my.app.usersList = ['Bill', 'Tom', 'Rick']
```

Is this possible? If so, is this a terrible idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to check, you don't need to users to have different roles (like admin) right?

Comment: Good question, Sérgio. No. Any user that accesses this application has the same role. It is a simple web front end to a database that our Business office needs. Users will only be me and a few Business office folks.

Answer (score 1):

That seems really silly. Why not have the list of users in a table? Then you can add/remove from that table without have to modify the application.

I currently do this and in my `UserDetailsContextMapper` I make sure the username already exists in the `User`s table.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom authenticator that will try to access your Active Directory and if authenticated, will look into Grails properties to check if the username is allowed to login.

This is the class that I use. I changed the code to validate the config:

```
class ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator {

  private DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextFactory
  private String principalSuffix = ""

  def grailsApplication

  public DirContextOperations authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

    // Grab the username and password out of the authentication object.
    String principal = authentication.getName() + "@" + principalSuffix
    String password = ""
    if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
      password = authentication.getCredentials().toString()
    }

    // If we have a valid username and password, try to authenticate.
    if (!("".equals(principal.trim())) && !("".equals(password.trim()))) {

      try {

        String provider  = contextFactory.getUrls()[0]

        Hashtable authEnv = new Hashtable(11)
        authEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory")
        authEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, provider)
        authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple")
        authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal)
        authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password)
        javax.naming.directory.DirContext authContext = new InitialDirContext(authEnv)


        //here validate the user against your config.
        if(!authentication.getName() in grailsApplication.config.adUsersAllowed) {
          throw new BadCredentialsException("User not allowed.")
        }

        DirContextOperations authAdapter = new DirContextAdapter()
        authAdapter.addAttributeValue("ldapContext", authContext)
        return authAdapter

      } catch ( NamingException ex ) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(ex.message)
      }

    } else {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect username or password")
    }
  }

  public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource getContextFactory() {
    return contextFactory
  }

  /**
   * Set the context factory to use for generating a new LDAP context.
   *
   * @param contextFactory
   */
  public void setContextFactory(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextFactory) {
    this.contextFactory = contextFactory
  }

  public String getPrincipalSuffix() {
    return principalSuffix
  }

  /**
   * Set the string to be prepended to all principal names prior to attempting authentication
   * against the LDAP server.  (For example, if the Active Directory wants the domain-name-plus
   * backslash prepended, use this.)
   *
   * @param principalPrefix
   */
  public void setPrincipalSuffix(String principalSuffix) {
    if (principalSuffix != null) {
      this.principalSuffix = principalSuffix
    } else {
      this.principalSuffix = ""
    }
  }

}
```

Declare it as your ldapAuthenticator in resources.groovy:

```
ldapAuthenticator(ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator) {
  contextFactory = ref('contextSource')
  principalSuffix = 'domain.local' //your domain suffix
  grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}
```

The downside is that you need to restart your context when you change config.groovy

In your controllers just use `@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that because annotations are resolved at compile time and not in runtime. Config properties will be read during the application runtime so you I fear you have to end up doing:

```
@Secured(["authentication.name in ['Bill', 'Tom', 'Rick']"])
class SomeController {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the `@Secured` annotation cannot be used for other things than comparing roles. But you should be able to do this with spring securities `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations. When using grails the easiest way to setup these annotations is installing the spring security ACL plugin.
Within `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` you can use SPEL expressions which are more flexible. Unfortunatelly SPEL does not provide an `in` operator. However you can delegate the security check to a service:

```
@PreAuthorize('@securityService.canAccess(authentication)')
public void test() {
    println "test?"
}
```

With the `@` symbol you can reference other beans like services within expression. Here the method `securityService.canAccess()` is called to evaluate if the logged in user can access this method.
To use this you have to configure a `BeanResolver`. I wrote some more details about configuring a `BeanResolver` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789822/grails-custom-security-evaluator/17794869#17794869).

Within `securityService` you can now do:

```
class SecurityService {
    def grailsApplication
    public boolean canAccess(Authentication auth) {
        return grailsApplication.config.myList.contains(auth.name)
    }    
}
```

In general I would not recommend to use a configuration value for validating the user in security checks. The groovy configuration will be compiled so you cannot easily add a new user without redeploying your application.